# maven Build Lifecycle with google app engine and google web toolkit

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, maven, build, lifecycle

Maven has the following default lifecycle steps:

```
validate - validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available
compile - compile the source code of the project
test - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or deployed
package - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
integration-test - process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run
verify - run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria
install - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally
deploy - done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.
```

maven gwt plugin supports: gwt:compile

maven gae plugin supports: gae:deploy

But the bottom two are not part of the default maven lifecycles ( at least from our pom ). So, on our build machine, what should we run on it?

We're currently running "mvn test gwt:compile gae:deploy". Is it right?

Answer (score 3):

Many plugins don't hook into the default lifecycle because they do "odd" things which are not generally useful. For example, the GWT compiler takes a long time.

If you want to add such plugins to a phase, use an `execution` block ([details](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/compile.html)):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This will invoke the goal `compile` of the plugin during the `compile` phase.

Note that for the GWT plugin, the `phase` is optional; if you invoke `compile`, the plugin will do the right thing.

`deploy` is a bit more hairy because of the phases left: Package is too early, it should after `test` and before `install`. So for `deploy`, you can experiment with different phases. If nothing works out, you still need to call `mvn test gae:deploy`

Comment: Note that gwt:compile binds to the pre-package phase by default, not the compile phase (so that it runs after the test phase)